# Am I applying the KCL the right way?

Tags: amplifier, nmos, small-signal

[image]

Applying KCL at the node where I have drawn the currents in order to find Vin/Vs,
I am not getting the correct answer which however I did obtain using the Voltage Divider. My question is, am I using the KCL wrong way?

Using KCL: Vin/Vs = (R/Rs)

Using Voltage divider (correct answer): Vin/Vout = R/(Rs+R)

The way I approached with KCL:

[image: My calculations]

Comment: I don't see any usage of KCL (and your math is poorly formatted, so it is difficult to read). Please show the detailed calculations.

Comment: Please show us your KCL equations. You should be able to determine the value of If by inspection, without doing any math. Can you see what its value must be?

Comment: here the assumption is (Rs/Rf=0) since Rs<<Rf.   KCl :I=Is+If ,i replaced the currents with corresponding Ohms relations. i.e.(Vin/R)=(Vs/Rs)+(Vf/If).

Comment: Show the calculation in a properly formatted way in the *question body*. You can [edit] yur question.

Comment: You should label all of the **nodes** in your circuit and express the voltage across each resistor as the difference between the voltages at two nodes. Which nodes are the gate, drain, and source? There is something fundamentally wrong with your schematic that you haven't seen yet.

Comment: I have already solved the other portions of this problem. All I need is, to find out the Vin/Vs and as a hint (Rs/Rf=0) is given. the equations is being demanded in this problem rather than numerical answer so..

Comment: But I can see that Vf **must be** zero, so there is something very wrong with your schematic. If you won't fix the schematic and label it properly why should anyone try to help you write equations for it?

Comment: This is two separate circuits - no common ground. There can be no current through Rf.

Comment: The circuit (even the naming of components) strongly suggests that this is the small signal equivalent circuit of a MOSFET connected to a voltage supply, bias, feedback and load resistors. However, in this case there would be a "common ground" (the bottom node of the two pieces of the circuit would be connected -- this would be the source terminal of the MOSFET). Therefore I suspect the circuit was drawn incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the initial equation should be:

$$\frac{Vs-Vin}{Rs}+\frac{Vo-Vin}{Rf}=\frac{Vin}{R}$$

assuming Rf is large, this simplifies to:

$$\frac{Vs-Vin}{Rs}=\frac{Vin}{R}$$

$$\frac{Vs}{Rs}-\frac{Vin}{Rs}=\frac{Vin}{R}$$

$$R Vs - R Vin = Rs Vin$$

$$R Vs = R Vin + Rs Vin = (Rs+R) Vin$$

$$\frac{Vin}{Vs}=\frac{R}{R+Rs}$$

Comment: This answer is not consistent with the OP's schematic...\$V_O-V_{IN}\$ must be zero according to the schematic, because \$I_f\$ must be zero. And we really don't like to handout homework answers here...we try to nudge the OP toward the answer, but this OP resisted all of the nudges.